# Looking for a Post-Constructor Event of a Control

Tags: c#, winforms, constructor, controls, paint

I have made a `Label` subclass and need to initialize a few of its Properties.

Some I can set in the constructor, but others are being reset in the designer code of the form, so they must be set

- after the designer has done its `InitializeComponent`
- but before the `Paint` event runs, which needs them in place.

Of course the control should be self-sufficient, so I can't add anything to the form's code.

I am using a workaround now: I set a flag `bool needsInit = true;` which I check in the `Paint` event. If true I call a `doInit()` method, which clears the flag and does the initializations.

It works, both for the running Form and for the VS Designer window.. but **I smell a flag**

So is there maybe a better, flagless way to do it? Or the Right Way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the InitLayout method.

```
protected override void InitLayout()
{
    // do something here
    base.InitLayout();
}
```