# Overridden ForeColor property gets reset when compiling

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a custom button inheriting from Control:

```
class MyButton : Control
    {
    ...
```

Inside this control I have overridden the ForeColor property like this:

```
public override Color ForeColor
{
    get
    {
        return _foreColor;
    }
    set
    {
        _foreColor = value;
        //Some other custom stuff is done here
    }
}
```

In the constructor of my MyButton I initialize various properties including the ForeColor:

```
public HMIButton() : base()
    {
        //Initialize default values
        SelectedForeColor = Color.White;
        ForeColor = Color.Black; 
        ...
    }
```

This way the properties are assigned the default values the FIRST time the button is dragged from the Toolbox to the form.
After this the properties are set in the .Designer.cs file of the form every time the project is compiled:

```
    // 
    // myButton1
    // 
    ...
    this.myButton1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(328, 148);
    this.myButton1.Name = "myButton1";
    this.myButton1.SelectedForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(30)))), ((int)(((byte)(30)))), ((int)(((byte)(30)))));
    ...
```

The problem is that the property ForeColor is not listed here, so every time I compile the application the value of ForeColor is reset back to the value set in the constructor.

I guess it has something to do with the fact that the ForeColor property is an ambient property.
I have tried to define ForeColor with the "new" keyword, but it makes no difference.

**My question is:** How can I force Visual Studio to set my ForeColor property from the .Designer.cs file like it does with various other properties?

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556506/looking-for-a-post-constructor-event-of-a-control), may be of use..

Comment: As I see it this is not what I need. I want the property to be set along with the other properties from the forms Designer.cs file.

Comment: Now it looks like this: public override Color ForeColor
{
    get
    {
        return _foreColor;
    }
    set
    {
        _foreColor = base.ForeColor = value;
        //Some other custom stuff is done here
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You changed the default value but you didn't tell the designer about it.  So it cannot reliably figure out whether or not the value should be persisted.  As far as it knows, your ForeColor property is still ambient and was never assigned.  It wasn't, you didn't use `base.ForeColor` in your property override.  You must use the [DefaultValue] attribute on the property to wisen it up:

```
[DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "255,0,0,0")]
public override Color ForeColor { get; set; }
```

Note how the attribute doesn't win any prizes, an inevitable side-effect of attribute constructors only supporting primitive types.  The other way to do it is by providing two private methods:

```
private bool ShouldSerializeForeColor() {
    return ForeColor != initialForeColor;
}
private new void ResetForeColor() {
    ForeColor = initialForeColor;
}
```

Where initialForeColor can now be a readonly variable.

Comment: I'm not sure I described the issue clearly enough. In the meanwhile I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915933/overridden-font-property-in-custom-usercontrol-not-displaying-in-designer-file?rq=1

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer, as your comment about base.ForeColor got me on the right track. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Now it looks like this: public override Color ForeColor { get { return _foreColor; } set { _foreColor = base.ForeColor = value; //Some other custom stuff is done here } }

Comment: Is there any point left in actually overriding the property?  I don't see one.

Comment: Yes, I draw the text manually in the Paint event, so in the setter I am calling a method that calculates the rectangle to draw inside, text angle etc.

Comment: Assigning the ForeColor property already triggers Paint, no need to help.  Changing a color doesn't change a rectangle.