# PropertyGrid - How can I set Default Color Value of a Property

Tags: vb.net, propertygrid

I have defined a Class for the PropertyGrid. Two of the properties are TextColor and TextFont. I am unable to set their default values either directly or through defining constants.

```
Private Const dTextColor As Color = Color.Black
```

doesn't allow me to set value. Same problem with setting up default Font constant.

Comment: Why does it need to be a Const if it is just the initial default?  `Public Property TextColor As Color = Color.Black` will work fine.

Comment: I am actually defining the constant first and then using the constant in the defaultvalue attribute as: DefaultValueAttribute(dTextColor). Using the ReadOnly dTextColor, removed the error from defining it. However, it doesnt accept the readonly dTextcolor in the DefaultValueAttribut().

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783386/overridden-forecolor-property-gets-reset-when-compiling/25786062#25786062

Answer (score 2):

You can not use `const` with `color` in .net.

> User-defined types, including classes, structs, and arrays, cannot be const.

For more details, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173119.aspx)

> The type specified in a constant declaration must be sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, float, double, decimal, bool, string, an enum-type, or a reference-type.

instead of using `Private Const dTextColor As Color = Color.Black` you can use `Private readonly dTextColor As Color = Color.Black`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a [ShouldSerialize and Reset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e(VS.71).aspx) method when the property is not a simple type. Here's an example where the default value is `Pink`:

```
Public Class Foo

    Public Property TextColor As Color = Color.Pink

    Private Function ShouldSerializeTextColor() As Boolean
        Return (Me.TextColor <> Color.Pink)
    End Function

    Private Sub ResetTextColor()
        Me.TextColor = Color.Pink
    End Sub

End Class
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Although Bjørn-Roger's solution is probably the best, you are able to use the `DefaultValue` attribute too. One of the overloads allows you to specify which type (`System.Type`) the default value is of and what the default value will be. However the "default value" parameter is a string, but the main system classes seems to be able to convert it to the correct value.

```
<DefaultValue(GetType(Color), "Black")> _
Public Property TextColor As Color = Color.Black
```